# How to take input from User in this scenario

Tags: c#, console-application

I am new to programming, RightNow I am following some online tutorials (from Microsoft). This is my code, so far I hardcoded values like cash to deposit or cash to withdraw, my question is very simple how to take input from the user.

```
        var savings = new SavingAccount("Saving Account", 10000);
        savings.MakeDeposite(1000, DateTime.Now, "Saving from Laptop");
        savings.MakeDeposite(525, DateTime.Now, "Saving from Hard-drive");
        savings.MakeWithdrawal(2500, DateTime.Now, "Needed for buying goods");
        savings.PerformMonthEndTransactions();
        Console.WriteLine(savings.GetAccountHistory());


        var currents = new CurrentAccount("Current Account", 0, 1000);
        currents.MakeDeposite(150000, DateTime.Now, "Salary Transfered");
        currents.MakeWithdrawal(25000, DateTime.Now, "Pay bills");
        currents.MakeWithdrawal(50000, DateTime.Now, "Rent");
        currents.PerformMonthEndTransactions();
        Console.WriteLine(currents.GetAccountHistory());
```

do I need to do some changes in the constructor as well? this is my constructor

```
    public BankAccount(string name, decimal initialBalance) : this(name, initialBalance, 0) { }

    public BankAccount(string name, decimal initialBalance, decimal minimumBalance)
    {
        //this.Owner = name;
        //this.Balance = initialBalance;
        this.Number = accountNumberSeed.ToString();
        accountNumberSeed++;

        this.Owner = name;
        this.minimumBalance = minimumBalance;
        if(initialBalance > 0)
        MakeDeposite(initialBalance, DateTime.Now, "Initial Balance");
    }
```

Comment: You can use [`Console.ReadLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=net-5.0) to get the input. Then convert that to the appropriate type. Ex: `decimal d = Decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per @Johnny Mopp, you can use `Console.ReadLine()` to get the input from user.

For example:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Specify your amount: ");

    if (decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out decimal amount))
        Console.WriteLine("amount entered: " + amount);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Conversion of user input to decimal failed.");
}
```

Comment: if you're going to use `TryParse` don't ignore the result!

Comment: @WanJun what is the reason behind it taking input from user in if else block? how decimal failed to parse? and what does mean by out decimal? please explain

Comment: @Jamiec Please answer to my coment

Comment: @Zong A user can enter anything `abc` cannot be parsed to a decimal for example. So doing it inside an `if..else` allows you to check  the result of `TryParse` which (as the name indicates) will return false if the input was not parseable to a decimal. The answer to what `out decimal` means is hidden in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=net-5.0)